# MySQL - Trying to order requested images from database by their upload date

Tags: mysql

So what i want to do is to create a request that will get images from my database and sort them in such a way, that images are grouped by the day they were uploaded and ordered by another number attached to them.
Meaning in practicle context:

```
           Upload-day  Number
Picture a: 05-04-2018     6
Picture b: 05-04-2018     3
Picture c: 04-04-2018     11
Picture d: 04-04-2018     10
```

*And so on...*

The issue I'm having here is, that if I group by the day they were uploaded I'll get days from various months and years, which is not intended.
I just can't figure out a way to include the year and month when trying to group the upload-dates without including the timestamp.

My **current approach** is as follows:

```
SELECT picture_id, file_id, posted_at, ..., pf.filename 
FROM picture join picturefile pf using (file_id) 
WHERE title LIKE %...% %' 
GROUP BY YEAR(posted_at), MONTH(posted_at), DAY(posted_at) 
ORDER BY likes DESC 
LIMIT 1,20;
```

The table picture here includes the posted_at attribute.

***Table Picture:***

```
#   Name            Typ           Collation       Standart  
1   picture_id (PK) int(11)                 
2   file_idIndex    int(11)     
3   usernameIndex   varchar(25)  utf8_general_ci             
4   location        varchar(250) utf8_general_ci             
5   likes           int(11)                           0
6   title           varchar(100) utf8_general_ci             
7   posted_at       datetime                       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP             
8   description     varchar(255) utf8_general_ci                 
9   rating_sum      int(11)             
10  rating_count    int(11)         
11  comment_option  int(11)         
12  x_coordinate    decimal(2,0)            
13  y_coordinate    decimal(2,0)
```

***Table Picturefile:***

```
Name                Typ           Collation         Standart    
1   file_id (PK)    int(11)                 
2   filenameIndex   varchar(100)  utf8_general_ci     NULL          
3   filetype        varchar(10)   utf8_general_ci     NULL
```

***My Request:***

```
SELECT picture_id, file_id, username, location, likes, title, posted_at, 
description, rating_sum, rating_count, comment_option, x_coordinate,
y_coordinate, pf.filename 
FROM picture join picturefile pf using (file_id) 
WHERE title LIKE '%these%' or '%really%' 
GROUP BY YEAR(posted_at),
MONTH(posted_at), DAY(posted_at) 
ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 1,20;
```

***Expected result:***

```
All named attributes with 
title:                           timestamp:             likes:

these oranges are very orange.    2018-12-13 08:12:13      0
magnificent. they really are.     2018-12-13 08:12:54      0
```

The values above are registered in the database.

Comment: So remove `DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(posted_at))` from your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also Google how to use proper `GROUP BY`.  Your query will not even run in any other dbms.

Comment: I've searched for the GROUP BY function using mysql but i can't seem to find another way. I've also delete FROM_UNIXTIME because it deemed to be useless. It's still not working. Am i missing something else crucial?

Comment: Please provide table structure, table relationship, sample input, expected output.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've updated the post with all necessary information. file_id and picture_id are identical, i've checked those.

Comment: Do you really need group by? May be just order by date and filtering `DATE_FORMAT(post_at, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` solve...

Comment: I was able to run the statement, but i didnt get anything back.